# Unexpected Replayer Termination 512

Tags: ios, xcode

When I run my application in iOS 11.3 iPhone7 using Xcode 9.3 and am getting following error message. Can anyone help me to figure out why this error message has appeared? I used the OC-Swift in my project, and use [[MTLCaptureManager alloc] startCaptureWithDevice: device]; invoke the GPU Frame Capture

[image]